# How to fix 'QML Debugger: Unable to listen to port'

Tags: qt, debugging, cmake, qml

I'm new to QML and have to work on a project started by a colleague.
When starting the application, I receive the following messages:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QML Debugger: Unable to listen to port 34567.
```

Due to that is a ROS project I have to work with cmake.

---

### System:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Qt Creator 4.9.2
- QT 5.8.0
- ROS Kinetic
- Enable QML in the Debugger settings

---

### What I've tried until now:

- restart system
- tried several ports
- checked, that no other Qt Application is started
- listen to port with netcat

---

### Code snippets:

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DQT_QML_DEBUG ")

set(TEMPLATE_QT_VERSION "5.8.0" CACHE STRING "Qt Version")
set(TEMPLATE_QT_MODULES Core Gui Widgets Quick Qml Concurrent Network DBus PrintSupport)

find_package(Qt5 ${TEMPLATE_QT_VERSION} EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED ${TEMPLATE_QT_MODULES})
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>

  #include <QQmlDebuggingEnabler>

  #include "ros/ros.h"
  #include "heartbeat/heartbeat.h" 
  #include <string.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include "message_handler/ros2tag.h"
  #include <QQmlContext>
  #include <QtCore/QDir>
  #include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
  #include <QtQml/QQmlEngine>
  #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
  #include "imageprovider.h"

  #include "qmlprox.h"
  #include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
  #include <QtCore/QDir>
  #include <QQmlEngine>

  #include <QList>
  #include <QString>

  #include "geodataprovider.h"
  #include "georeferenceddatalistmodel.h"
  #include "georeferenceddatatriplelistmodel.h"
  #include "parameterdatalistmodel.h"
  #include "parameterdata.h"
  #include "beetImageHandler.h"




  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

      QQmlDebuggingEnabler enabler;

      //Initialisierung Knoten
      ros::init(argc, argv, "hmi");
      ros::NodeHandle n;
```

**ROS-Launchfile:**

```
<launch>
  <arg name="externParameters" default="0" />
  <group ns="hmi">
    <node name="hmi" pkg="hmi" type="hmi" respawn="true" respawn_delay="10" args="-qmljsdebugger=port:34567" />
  </group>
</launch>
```

Due to the ROS launch-file the application is started with the argument "-qmljsdebugger=port:34567".

Can anyone of you give me please an hint or a solution for my problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just an idea, you can give a port range instead of a single port: `-qmljsdebugger=port:34000;35000`, maybe this will help. One thing you can do to test if it is a general issue or a QML debugger specific issue is try to instantiate your own `QTcpServer` and see if you can listen on any port. For information, you can see the code that generates the error message here: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/plugins/qmltooling/qmldbg_tcp/qtcpserverconnection.cpp.html#168

Comment: Trying -qmljsdebugger=port:3400,3500: 'QML Debugger: Unable to listen to ports 34000 - 35000.'. I will try to instantiate a QTcpServer and comment the results here.

Comment: I tried to instantiate my own QTcpServer, which worked without problems. When  I tried to 'QTcpServer::listen`, I got: `The proxy type is invalid for this operation`.  Using NetworkProxy::NoProxy` and everything is ok. I also tried to debug a new QML-Project and got the same error: `QML Debugger: Unable to listen to port 34567.`

Comment: Now I'm using Qt12.4 and eyerything is working...